# Fluent validation in Nop commerce - alphanumeric only

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce, fluentvalidation

I'm trying to make the zip / postal code field in Nop Commerce 2.65 into an alphanumeric only field. I've edited the file AddressValidator.cs in the Nop.Web admin folder with the following line:

```
 RuleFor(x => x.ZipPostalCode)
            .Matches(@"^[0-9a-zA-Z ]+$")
            .WithMessage("Numbers and letters only please.");
```

I've compiled and uploaded the NopAdmin.dll but it does nothing, it's like the validation is not there.

Is the code wrong or am I uploading the wrong file?

Comment: Does it do anything when you try 55555 or 55555#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just tested your code and it works just fine. I presume you forgot to re-build the Nop.Admin project once modified. Also note that the solution has two "AddressValidator" classes. Please ensure that you modified the required one

Answer (score 1):

There was nothing wrong with the logic in my question, just the source file I was editing! There are two addressvalidation.cs files, one in admin, one in web. I hadn't realised the web one existed hence my edits were not working.

Applying the code in my question to the other AddressValidator.cs file worked fine.